# Assertion Error During Running the program

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I made a program in Visual Studio 2008 using C++ language and MFC Files. It is a graphical user interface which store student records in a file using file handling of C++. It  is working properly and shows or adds records but when I try to modify and delete records it will give a assertion error to me while running.

Please help me out.

Functions code that I use for modify and delete records are here.

```
void modifyrec()
{
    Invalidate();

    bool found;

    struct student e;

    getname_dialog diag;
    if(diag.DoModal()==IDOK)
    {
        found = false;

        fp.SeekToBegin();

        while(fp.Read(&e,sizeof(e))>=sizeof(e))
        {
            if(e.batch_no==g_batchno && strcmp(e.name,g_name)==0)
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(found == true )
        {
            modify_dialog mdiag(e);
            mdiag.DoModal();
        }
        else
            MessageBox("Record Not Found","Modify Record....");
    }
}

void delrec()
{
    bool foun;
    struct student e;

    Invalidate();

    getname_dialog diag;
    if(diag.DoModal()==IDOK)
    {
        found = false;
        fp.SeekToBegin();

        CFile ft("temp.dat",CFile::modeCreate | CFile:modeWrite);
        while(fp.Read(&e,sizeof(e))>= sizeof(e))
        {
            if(e.batch_no==g_batchno && strcmp(e.name,g_name)==0)
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(found == true )
        {
            modify_dialog mdiag(e);
            mdiag.DoModal();
        }
        else
            MessageBox("Record Not Found","Delete Record....");


        fp.Close();
        ft.Close();

        CFile::Remove("students.dat");
        CFile::Rename("temp.dat","student.dat");
        fp.Open("students.dat",CFile::modeCreate |CFile::modeNoTruncate |CFile::modeReadWrite);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the assertion error say! Looking at the code I can see a logic error in delrec but nothing that would cause an assertion error.

Comment: The answer appears to be in the code not shown.

Comment: i will paste the whole programme code right now if you guys say or it was helpfull to  tell about the error

Comment: Paste the assertion error message first.

Comment: okkkzz the error message says : Debug Assertion Failed !
visual studio 2008\projects\file input output\Debug\file input output.exe
File: f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\dlgdata.cpp
Line:40

For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on Asserts.

Comment: it also have 3 buttons on error message box "About","Retry","Ignore"

Comment: it show a break point arrow in dlgdata.cpp file on Line 40 and the statement is ASSERT(FALSE);

Comment: Well I think that error is something to do with how you are using your dialog boxes, it's not a problem in the code you've posted. Something in the getname_dialog or modify_dialog classes perhaps.

Comment: Posting a line or two of code before ASSERT(FALSE) might help.

Comment: HWND CDataExchange::PrepareCtrl(int nIDC)
{
 ASSERT(nIDC != 0);
 ASSERT(nIDC != -1); // not allowed
 HWND hWndCtrl;
   COleControlSite* pSite = NULL;
 m_pDlgWnd->GetDlgItem(nIDC, &hWndCtrl);
 if (hWndCtrl == NULL)
 {
   // Could be a windowless OCX
   pSite = m_pDlgWnd->GetOleControlSite(nIDC);
   if (pSite == NULL)
   {
     TRACE(traceAppMsg, 0, "Error: no data exchange control with ID 0x%04X.\n", nIDC);
     ASSERT(FALSE);
     AfxThrowNotSupportedException();
   }
 }
 m_idLastControl = nIDC;
 m_bEditLastControl = FALSE; // not an edit item by default

   return hWndCtrl;
}

Comment: Amazed to know that no one is able to help me out for this problem

Comment: I'd be amazed if anyone could help given the quality of the question. You expected us to guess the error message and only posted the assertion in an unreadable comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You seem to have removed one or more controls from the dialog resource, and `DoDataExchange` is still referring them (via of one DDX_Control functions). Find out what those resources are, and remove the references of them from `DoDataExchange`.

Later you may remove those control IDs (`IDC_`) from resource.h altogether if they are **not used** by other dialogs in your project.

To find out unused resource IDs do:

- Goto Resource View
- Select the appropriate .RC file
- Right click and click `Resource Symbols..`
- In the dialog box, find out unused IDs (not having check at them)

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved my time. Finaly I fixed bug